# How do I render an image based on a variable which contains the image link?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm building a simple web application that stores data.

I am struggling in the part where I have to render a specific image based on a link.
I created a CSV file that looks like this:
[image: my CSV file]

Now, I created a dictionary based on this file where whatever there is under the `OBJECT` column is set as a key, and whatever there is under the `IMAGE_LINK` column, is set as a value.

I want to render that picture in my HTML file. I tried with jinja, but it does not seem to work.
Here's what I tried to do

```
[...]
<h2>You are storing: <span style="color:red">{{ object_selling }}</span></h2>
    
    <img alt="{{ category }}" src="{{ shoe_image }}" width="150" height="64">
    
    <form action="" method="post">
[...]
```

this is wat I get on the page:

[image: Result of the HTML code shown above]

which is obviously not the expected result.

Do you have a way to declare a variable and use it inside an img tag using python, flask, and HTML?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is happening.
Because this should normally work fine:

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/FpUpfYz.png">
```

I would make sure that `{{shoe_image}}` actually contains the link.
to test this either print the variable in python or put this in your html file:

`{{shoe_image}}`

This should display your link, if not then you need to set the variable to the link.